# Recursion, pass function as an argument

Tags: javascript

I want to run a function certain amount of times using recursion, for example: `repeat(console.log('Hello'), 3)` should print Hello 3 times. I tried to implement such function but it prints only one word `Hello`.

```js
function repeat(w, x){
        let fun = function(arg){
            return arg
        }
        if (x==1){
            return fun(w)
          }
          else{
            return fun(w)+repeat(fun(w), x-1)
        }
    }
  repeat(console.log('Hello'), 3)
```

Comment: Could you add an example on how you would call this function, initially ?

Comment: @Nicolas He did in the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few mistakes in your code:

1. You're not passing the function as an argument.
2. You don't need to use `+` to make two functions run after each other. From your original snippet I infer that you're only concerned about the side effects, not the values. So you can just call the functions individually.

It could look something like this:

```js
  function repeat(fun, x) {
   if(x < 1) return; // we ran out of attempts, terminate
   fun(); // side-effect (print to console)
   repeat(fun, x - 1); // decrement the counter and attempt to continue
}
    
repeat(function() { console.log("hello")}, 3);
```

Answer (score 5):

You're not passing the function as an argument. You're calling the function and passing its return value.

Just pass `fun` with no argument list. In the initial call, you can use an anonymous function.

```js
function repeat(fun, x) {
  if (x == 1) {
    return fun()
  } else {
    return fun() + repeat(fun, x - 1)
  }
}

repeat(() => console.log("Hello"), 3);
console.log(repeat((a = 0) => a + 1, 5));
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to add values together, though. This type of functions is not used to replace `reduce` but rather to limit execution of side-effects (like in the example given).

Comment: My second example shows the sense of adding together. Of course, that means this function can't be used for other combination operations.

Comment: Yes, your second example does show that (hence my comment about `reduce`). I'd argue that the `+` in the original snippet is not intended and comes from general misunderstanding of how to control flow in this scenario. Anyhow, good answer  

Comment: Good point. I was trying to avoid changing too many things in his code. If you explain in your answer why it's inappropriate I'll upvote you.

Answer (score 3):

This code has a recursive function that accept a function and number of times to execute it.

```js
function repeat(func, x){
    if(x === 0) return;
    func(x);
    repeat(func, x - 1);
}

repeat((x) => {console.log(`Hello ${x}`)}, 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need pass a function and maybe use a iteraror like `for(){}` to repeat `x` times

```js
function repeat(w, x){
    for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        w.call()
    }
}

repeat(()=>console.log("Foo"),4)
```

Comment: Using recursion is a requirement, apparently. I'm guessing, it's a course assignment of some sort.

Comment: If is a requirement I guess best the other answers :D

Answer (score 1):

When calling the function `repeat(console.log('Hello'), 3)`, you are assiging the returns value of the function `console.log('Hello')` as the value of the parameter `w`. This causes your function to show only one console log, and assigning undefined to the parameters `w`. What you are looking for might be to pass a function reference as the first parameters, the argument to that function as the second parameters and the number of call as a third parameters.

```js
function repeat(func, arguments, x){
    if (x==1){
        return func.call(this, arguments);
      }
      else{
        return func.call(this, arguments)+repeat(func, arguments, x-1)
    }
}

repeat(console.log, 'Hello', 3);
```

Note here that i've removed the variable `fun` and moved it as a parameters.

Also, when you want to pass a reference to a function as an argument, you don't use the parenthesis ( `( )` ). This is what i've done here.

I'm also using the `.call` function on that first parameters, to call it dynmically. The syntax of the `call` function goes like this `call( thisContext, ...arguments)`. You can learn more on that function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)